# Choosing numbers from an interval

Tags: probability

We draw $10$ numbers from an interval $[0,5]$. Compute probability, that at least two of these numbers will land in $[1,3]$.

So if $A-$ at least two numbers land in an interval $[1,3]$, then:

$A'-$ none of the numbers or only one will land in $[1,3]$, and it gives me:

$\Bbb P(A')=\frac{\lambda_{10}([0,1)\cup(3,5])+10 \cdot\lambda_{9}([0,1)\cup(3,5])\cdot\lambda_1([1,3]) }{\lambda_{10}([0,5])}$

where $\lambda_a$ is a Lebesgue measure for a  cartesian product of intervals  in $\Bbb R^a.$

Then

$\Bbb P(A)=1-\Bbb P(A')=1-\frac{\lambda_{10}([0,1)\cup(3,5])+10 \cdot\lambda_{9}([0,1)\cup(3,5])\cdot\lambda_1([1,3]) }{\lambda_{10}([0,5])}=1-\frac{3^{10}+10*3^9*2}{5^{10}}=0.9536$

Am I right?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: The question is missing the information about the distribution of the draws, presumably independent and apparently uniform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $U\sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,5).$ Call it a Success if $1 \le U\le 3.$ Then the probability of a Success is $2/5 = 0.4.$ In R,

```
diff(punif(c(1,3), 0, 5))
[1] 0.4
```

Then the number $X$ of Successes in 10 independent Bernoulli trials
has $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=10, p=.4).$ You seek
$$P(X \ge 2) = 1 - P(X \le 1) = 0.9536,$$ which agrees with your numerical answer. In R,

```
1 - pbinom(1, 10, .4)
[1] 0.9536426
```